# Calling a URL from manifest to HTML file for web browser

Tags: html, iframe, environment-variables, manifest, iframe-app

I'm looking to take a variable or statement from my manifest (below) and place it in an HTML file. I think it's a reasonably straightforward process but for some reason, I cannot figure out how to get the two to speak with one another. Can I get some help on how to complete this?

Manifest:

```
applications:
  name: application
  instance: 1
  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
  host: application-hostTenant
  memory: x amount
  display: browser 
  **url: https://iframe-tenant.apps.eu1.mindsphere.io**
  description: "A simple app using the iframe method to host an outside 
  application/link. The link/app is specified in the url"
```

Assume that the iFrame/HTML call is similar (below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
        <title>Basic Title</title>
    </head>

<iframe src="url from the Manifest" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="myIFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%px" width="100%px" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</html>
```

There doesn't need to be anything else on the web page other than the iframe and access to it.